# How repeated links in home page affect to link juice?

Tags: seo, links

Home pages usually have repeated links, as categories menu on header and footer. An other example would be the home page link on header menu and the logo image which is the link anchor.

Does it affect to link juice? I know that Google just reads once the repeated links in a page, but I'm not sure if it makes lose link juice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeating a link will not cause extra PageRank to be passed to that page, nor will it cause link juice to get lost.

Google usually only pays attention to the anchor text from the *first* link.

If one of the links has a rel nofollow on it, then Google treats all the duplicate links as if they were nofollowed. (Why should they trust any if you say they can't trust one?)  So don't try to use nofollow to tell Google *which* of the duplicate links it should pay attention to.

Adding a different anchor to each link (`#anchor`) causes the duplicate links to be de-duplicated and Google passes PageRank and anchor text to all of them.  It is unclear if this then helps the full target page, or just sections of it.

Links with nofollow and links to pages that are disallowed in robots.txt *do* cause your site's pagerank to evaporate.  In practice, that doesn't seem to matter much.  Rankings don't drop when nofollows are applied to unimportant internal links, nor do they improve when they are removed.  Google seems to have some way of compensating sites where a large portion of the internally passed PageRank evaporates.

Comment: Great answer! Basing on what you say about different anchor to same link, how then the logo link should be treated? It doesn't have any anchor text, so it will be always different from other home page links.

Comment: Internal anchor text isn't used much as a ranking signal these days as far as I can tell.  I haven't worried to much about getting it "just right" since about 2010.  For image links, you can put an alt text on the image which is very similar to regular anchor text.  It is also possible that Google will get the anchor text from the first non-image link -- I haven't done any testing in that area.   However it works, it isn't something that is worth worrying about these days.   Getting your internal anchor text correct just isn't worth the time because it doesn't boost rankings like it used to.